# Validation errors when using echo PHP variable as value of input field

Tags: php, w3c-validation

I have a simple HTML form and I use PHP to validate user input. If there are errors in the form I redisplay the form, keeping the values that are okay so the user can modify only the fields that have errors. Everything works as expected but when I tried validating the markup I got errors on this line:

```
<input type="text" name="hours" value="<?php echo $hoursWorked; ?>" />
```

Here's the function that redisplays the form:

```
  function redisplayForm($hoursWorked, $hourlyWage) {
    ?> <h2 style = "text-align:center">Paycheck Form</h2>
    <form action="process_Paycheck.php" method="post">
    <p>Hours Worked: <input type="text" name="hours" value="<?php echo $hoursWorked;?>" /></p>
    <p>Hourly Wage: <input type="text" name="wage" value="<?php echo $hourlyWage;?>" /></p>
    <p><input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />&nbsp;
        &nbsp;<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Form" /></p>
    </form>
    <?php }
```

When I uploaded the .php source file to validate the markup I got these error messages and for each of these errors the opening " after value= is highlighted in red:

> Character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
>
> Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
>
> Attributes construct error

How can I fix this so I don't get validation errors?

Comment: the question is unclear. What's the value of `$hoursWorked` and how is that input being used, on its own or in already opened php tags?

Comment: try `htmlentities` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Where **exactly** are you seeing these _"errors"_? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I edited my post to explain `$hoursWorked`. The form has 2 input fields "hours worked" and "hourly wage" and both fields need to have some input and the input has to be numeric.

Comment: @softengstu the question was _"What's the value of `$hoursWorked`"_ and you have **not** answered it

Comment: @Phil the value of `$hoursWorked` depends on the user input. There's a field in the form called "hours worked" and the user enters a value. That value is stored in the variable `$hoursWorked`. `$hoursWorked = validateInput($_POST['hours'], "Hours Worked");`

Comment: Then give us an example value, one that triggers the error. I mean, you've provided next to no information about your problem... There's absolutely no context for the single line of code you've provided. You haven't said where / how you see this _"error"_. You haven't said if the error is caused by any particular value for `$hoursWorked` and you've barely addressed any of the questions asked in the comments

Comment: The errors aren't triggered by any input. The errors are on https://validator.w3.org/check when I upload my .php source file markup to validate it.

Comment: And exactly what _"markup"_ are you uploading? The `.php` source file or the rendered HTML?

Comment: The .php source file

Comment: PHP is a scripting language. The W3 validator validates HTML. These are **very different things**.

Comment: I was trying to validate the (X)HTML markup so I copied everything from my php source fie and pasted it into the 'Validate by Direct Input' section of the W3C validator.

Comment: If you're going to validate anything, open the page in your browser, _"View Source"_ and copy that markup, not your PHP source

Answer (score 0):

As you have already known from the comments, the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org) cannot be used to validate the PHP files. If the page can be accessed from the Internet then use its URL, otherwise use the browser's "View Source" command to view the generated HTML and copy-paste the HTML into the validator.

This is not a limitation of W3C Validator. There is no way to validate the HTML by looking at the PHP source. PHP is a dynamic language, by executing the code you can get different HTML output depending on the input.

Without using any validator, the code you posted has one strong flaw: if `$hoursWorked` is a string that contains `"` (double quotes), the generated HTML is incorrect pieces of markup are rendered as text by the browser.

Imagine what happens if `$hoursWorked` is `'2">'`. The generated HTML is:

```
<input type="text" name="hours" value="2">" />
```

and the fragment `" />` becomes visible in the rendered output because it is not part of the markup any more.

This is what happens when dynamic content is rendered as HTML without being properly encoded as HTML. PHP provides the function [`htmlspecialcharacters()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) that must always be used to properly encode (as HTML) content that is used to generate HTML. Especially when the content is retrieved from an outside source (from the browser, f.e.). The code should be:

```
<input type="text" name="hours" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($hoursWorked); ?>" />
<input type="text" name="wage" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($hourlyWage); ?>" />
```

Other than that, the HTML generated by the posted code looks fine.